# Get sapui5 element byId Like

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a list. Inside each row I have an input with the next ID:
input_row_1, input_row_2...

I'm working with navigationContainer so, when I'm trying to find by Id, I note that the real ids are something like: xlmview--1--input_row_1--list. So I can't find them.

Is there any way to find all the inputs with one search. Something like:

```
this.getView().byId("*input_row*");
```

If there isn't, how can I get one input by Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can get all list item and then iterate through each items to find input of each list items.

```
var urListAllItems=sap.ui.getCore().byId("your list id").getItems();
```

> once you have your array of items you can loop through each items and do what you want to.